# How to intercept the "Show Desktop" event?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

I'm looking for a way to intercept the ShowDesktop event and set my window at front.
Is there a way doing it without using API hooks?
Thanks,
Omer.

Comment: Please don't do this. You don't own the computer, the user of your program does. If they don't want to see your program, that's their choice.

Comment: I hope not. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly terrible idea.

Comment: What if the user ran two such programs? Raymond has the [answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx), as always!

Comment: I'm writing a dock, hence, displaying it always on the desktop is mandatory.

Comment: @John: something like StarDock or RocketDock 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_(computing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing a Windows taskbar style dock then simply make sure your window has `WS_EX_TOPMOST` set and 'Show Desktop' will leave it alone.  Alternatively use `SetWindowPos` to make it the top-most window after it has been created, e.g.:

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE);
```

Update: You need to use the Windows Application Bar API to make a 'dock' style app.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969323.aspx) for more details.

Application bars also need to be removed from the top-level list displayed when you Alt+Tab etc, which can be done by adding the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` and removing `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`.

I should of made this clear earlier, apologies.

Comment: Works for my taskbar-style app which uses the Windows AppBar API.

Comment: I started with the empty Win32 project. Don't know why that didn't work.

Comment: I'ts really weird, it works now but it didn't worked for me before (it was always on top except when i clicked on the toggle desktop button and then it made it disappear)
Maybe it was caused because of some style\ex style combination.
Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: oh and BTW, I don't want to use the AppBar API because I don't want to reserve any screen space.

Comment: My problem is, that I want to create a Desktop-Replacement and my application therefore is _bottom-most_ instead of _top-most_ - do you maybe have any hints/ideas to solve the issue?