# Detect that Window is minimized by Win+D when ShowInTaskbar="False"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm not asking for an event. I'm asking how to ask (using C#, not WinAPI) "is the Window minimized?".

`WindowState` is not good enough. When `ShowInTaskbar="False"` this will be `Normal` after Win+D. Try it with `Debug.WriteLine(WindowState);` in a Timer.

**So**, is there a reliable managed way to check if the Window is minimized (even when `ShowInTaskbar` is `False`)?

Comment: If you want to know if the Window Is Minized, that is a very different quetion from "was Win+D used". What Win+D does, is call the "Show Desktop" Function of the Explorer wich minimizes all Windows. Plus maybe also setting the Input Focus on the desktop? You can also call it by rightclicking on the Taskbar.

Comment: @Christopher I mean Win+D as opposed to the minimize button on the Window which _will_ change the `WindowState` and even raise the StateChanged event.

Comment: @ColinSmith I'd need to create a Winforms Form in a WPF app. Not impossible, but I'll stick around to see if there's some simpler solution. Thanks.

Comment: A couple of ideas here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/12102737-ebe2-46b0-8f92-83f7c0687c64/toggledesktop?forum=windowsuidevelopment .... the main ideas is to hook the ToggleDesktop() call....so that you know it's been "called", or hook the WIN+D keypress (but of course that doesn't help if someone shows desktop via the Taskbar showdesktop click)...or use a timer to detect changes in the zorder. Or set your window to TopMost....but then you are unlikely to want that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477961/how-to-intercept-the-show-desktop-event

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `IsIconic` WinAPI function, the declaration is the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
```

`hWnd` is Window handle, you can get it using `WindowInteropHelper` class. [PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.isiconic) also has some examples

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it returns false.

Comment: @ispiro Based on the name I would guess it is supposed to return false if you are minimized - aka not "Iconic".

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic): `Determines whether the specified window is minimized (iconic).` But anyway, I tested it and it shows true when minimized by the minimized button on the Window.